# Shell script being executed on remote machine exits after running make command

Tags: bash, shell-script, make

I'm trying to automate installing Erl using shell script. Here's my shell script-

```
unzip OTP-18.0-rc1.zip
cd otp-OTP-18.0-rc1

export ERL_TOP=`pwd`
./otp_build autoconf
./configure
echo $ERL_TOP
echo "################### MAKE ###################"
make -j8 && make install

echo "Creating soft links......"
ln -snf /home/user/erlang/otp-OTP-18.0-rc1/bin/erl /usr/bin/erl
ln -snf /home/user/erlang/otp-OTP-18.0-rc1/bin/erlc /usr/bin/erlc

# Install other packages
```

I'm trying to execute this script on a remote machine this way-

```
ssh root@host_ip 'bash -s' < my_script.sh
```

However the script exits after the make command, without creating the soft links.
I've verified that there's no error during install process. Also the script works perfectly fine when executed locally on that same system.

Interestingly, if I modify the script to put `make` command on two separate lines like this-

```
make -j8
make install
```

The script exits without doing `make install`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked to see that `make -j8` returns an exit code of 0?

Comment: might be worth adding one or more `-v` flags to your ssh to see if it's getting a signal, or exiting for some other reason

Comment: @saiarcot895 No I haven't. I guess that could be a reason.How can check that? And if it's returning exit code of 0, how can i make sure my script execution is not interrupted. Thanks.

Comment: Watch what happens by adding the `-x` flag to `bash` like this - `ssh root@host_ip 'bash -xs' < my_script.sh`. Another possibility is that the `make -j8` command has a dependency on the terminal (use `ssh -t ...`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you can have only 1 stdin, and so if your bash script runs a command that reads from stdin at all, it will gobble up lines from the script.

Try resetting stdin for the make commands, eg:

```
( make -j8 && make install ) </dev/null
```

Comment: This seems to be working. However I'm curious why i didn't faced the same issue while installing Openssl on my machine, since even there i was doing the same thing `make` followed by `make install` ?

Comment: A makefile runs arbitrary shell commands; it will read from stdin only if those commands do. What exactly the makefile runs will make all the difference.

Answer (score 3):

meuh's answer works for you, but here's another option:

```
scp my_script.sh root@host_ip:/tmp/
ssh root@host_ip bash /tmp/my_script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind explaining what changes if we run the script after copying on the remote machine.

Comment: The problem was caused by redirection of stdin.  by copying and running the script, there is no redirection of stdin.